# Illegal assignment from LIST to SET

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to query records and collect them in a Set as below

```
Set<abc__c> a = [select id from abc__c limit 2];
```

but getting the following error **Illegal assignment from LIST to SET**.Can't I collect the result of a query in Set ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is simple way:

```
Set<Account> acc = new Set<Account>([SELECT id from Account]);
```

**You cannot type cast a `List<sObjectType>` to `Set<sObjectType>` just by query assignment, pass it to `Set` constructor instead.**

Answer (score 2):

```
//Fetching all account in map
 Map<id,abc__c> aMap = new Map<id,abc__c>([select id from abc__c limit 2]);

 Set<Id> a=aMap.keyset();
```

You cannot directly collect in set and using maps save script statements and avoiding loops .

Comment: In the second statement keySet() method will only return the ID's and not set of sobject. I think the second statement will error out